# How do you debug the bug that only appears when the load is huge?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

We are currently developing a cluster manager software in C. If several nodes connect to the manager, it works perfect, but if we use some tools to simulate 1000 nodes to connect the manager, it will sometimes work in unexpected ways.

How can one debug this kind of bug? It only appears when the load(connection/nodes) is large?

If I use `gdb` to debug step by step, the app never malfunctions.

Comment: Presumably it is a data race?

Comment: Standard questions: Does the code compile without warnings, even with highest warning level? What does Valgrind (or any other memory checker) tell you?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on which kind of malfunction you are observing? Is it a simple crash, or more a subtitle misbehaviour of the logic implemented. Or in between?

Comment: You have logging code that logs everything, right? And can run at variable log levels?  Logging everything like every function call, including arguments and actual return values?  And no, `printf()` to `stdout` is not real logging.

Comment: Yes, compile with `-Wall -ggdb3`, no warnings, there's also no warning in valgrind check. misbehaviour is that we cannot get expected results(output from manager), for example, expected `down: 2`, got `down: 0`

Comment: Add `-Wextra -pedantic` at least. Probably `-Wconversion` as well, where as the later would most likely confront with the need for a lot of reviews ...

Comment: Is it multi-threading application?  If not, it sounds like an uninitialized variable bug, valgrind should have told you about it. Are you sure it did not? In multi-threaded app it might be a synchronization issue.

Comment: What @AndrewHenle says.  Comprehensive logging can help when a conventioal debugger cannot, eg. with intermittent or load-dependent bugs in complex, distributed systems.  Keep a log of everythng that happens, time, logfiles, symptoms etc.  It's hard, but you will eventually narrow it down and, (hopefully), fix it.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142743/35384

Comment: @Serge *Is it multi-threading application? If not, it sounds like an uninitialized variable bug.* Don't **guess**.  You're almost certainly going to be wrong.  Guessing to solve problems like this wastes time, and while you're guessing and changing code and hoping to fix the bug, you're likely introducing new bugs.  See [Easter egging](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/Easter-egging) and [shotgun debugging](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/shotgun%20debugging)

Comment: A bit old, but conceptionally OK: https://sourceware.org/gdb/talks/esc-west-1999/

Comment: Well , 'guessing' can lead to additional information that can help to narrow down the real bug.  As long as 'symptoms disappeared' is not automatically read as 'bug fixed', then changing stuff around, in an attempt to change the scope or severity of the symptoms and so provde more information, is a valid debugging technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to debug this kind of bug?

In general, you want to use at least these techniques:

1. Make sure the code compiles and links without warnings. The `-Wall` is a good start, but `-Wextra` is better.
2. Make sure the application has designed-in logging and tracing, which can be turned on or off, and which has sufficient details to debug these kinds of issues, and low overhead.
3. Make sure the code has good unit-test coverage.
4. Make sure the tests are sanitizer-clean.

> there's also no warning in valgrind check.

It's not clear whether you've simply ran the target application under Valgrind, or whether you also have the unit tests, and the tests are Valgrind-clean. It's also not clear whether you've observed the application mis-behavior under Valgrind or not.

Valgrind used to be the best tool available for heap and unintialized memory problems, but in 2017 this is no longer the case.

Compiler-based [Address](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), [Thread](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual) and [Memory](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer) sanitizers catch significantly wider class of errors (e.g. global and stack overflows, and data races), and you should run your unit tests under all of them.

When all of the above still fails to find the problem, you may be able to run the real application instrumented with sanitizers.

Lastly, there are tools like [GDB tracing](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html) and [systemtap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) -- they are harder to learn, but give you significant power. Overview [here](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/07/05/linux-tracing-systems/).

Answer (score 4):

Sadly the debugger is less useful for debugging concurrency/load issues.

Keep adding logs/printfs, trigger the issue with load testing, then try to narrow it down with more logs/printfs. Repeat.

The faster it is to trigger the bug the faster this will converge. Also prefer the classic "bisection" / "binary search" technique when adding logs - try to narrow down the areas you're looking at by at least half every time.

Comment: Logging should have been designed in from the start.  And I mean *real* logging - not `printf()` to `stdout`.  Because the easiest way to find bugs like this is have the code tell you what it's *really* doing.

Comment: ... and to not slow down the program (which is important when facing issues with multi-threaded/-process applications) by doing massive debug logging,  use any asynchronous log-mechanics, as for example the "syslogd" service.

Comment: Excellent points. If the bug can't be triggered anymore it's useless.

Comment: @orip even that information is useful.  If something 'fixes' the bug, (ie. hides its symptoms for now), or, better, makes the bug much worse, it's a valuable clue.  Even 'doing X makes no difference whatsoever' is useful information.